# How to allow + characters in user with passport-local strategy?

Tags: node.js, passport-local, passport.js

I'm using the `passport-local` strategy with email addresses. This results in problems with gmail addresses with a generic plus part eg. `example+test@gmail.com`.

Using

```
import passport from 'passport';
import passportLocal from 'passport-local';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';


var LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, pass, cb) {
  // Store hash in your password DB.
  console.log("Passwort:LocalStrategy:Email", email);
  ...
})
```

the console log is `example test@gmail.com`. Logins works if I replace the plus with a blank in the database.

How can I make passport allow plus in username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented passport-local in my project and it does allow a plus - no extra code needed. Are you sure it's passport that's rejecting the + and not some other validation middleware?

Comment: Thx for the hint. Problem was caused by the angular 2 http encoding. Had to manually encode.